# or operator in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have some data like this :

```
db.movies.insert([
    {
        title : "Fight Club",
        writer : "Chuck Palahniuk",
        year : 1999,
        actors : [
          "Brad Pitt",
          "Edward Norton",
        ]
    },
    {
        title : "Pulp Fiction",
        writer : "Quentin Tarantino",
        year : 1994,
        actors : [
          "John Travolta",
          "Uma Thurman",
        ]
    },
    {
        title : "Inglorious Basterds",
        writer : "Quentin Tarantino",
        year : 2009,
        actors : [
          "Brad Pitt",
          "Diane Kruger",
          "Eli Roth",
        ]
    },
    {
        title : "The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey",
        writer : "J.R.R. Tolkein",
        year : 2012,
        franchise : "The Hobbit",
    },
    {
        title : "The Hobbit: The Desolation of Smaug",
        writer : "J.R.R. Tolkein",
        year : 2013,
        franchise : "The Hobbit",
    },
    {
        title : "The Hobbit: The Battle of the Five Armies",
        writer : "J.R.R. Tolkein",
        year : 2012,
        franchise : "The Hobbit",
        synopsis : "Bilbo and Company are forced to engage in a war against an array of combatants and keep the Lonely Mountain from falling into the hands of a rising darkness.",
    },
    {
        title : "Pee Wee Herman's Big Adventure"
    },
    {
        title : "Avatar"
    }
])
```

I need to get all movies released before the `year` 2000 or after 2010, So I'm writing this query:

```
db.movies.find( {$or: [{"year" : {$gt:2010,$lt:2000}}]})
```

But I'm not getting any output. Please suggest.

Comment: it's not possible to have a year greater than 2010 and less than 2000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert multiple data use `db.movies.insertMany([])` option.

to achieve this you can try it like this

```
db.movies.find({ $or: [{ "year": { $gt: 2010 } }, { "year": { $gt: 2000 } }] })
```

you can check this for proper documentation here
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/